# Flutter Admob check if BannerAd is loaded to lay out UI

Tags: android, flutter, admob

I plan to show a banner ad for my app on the top of the screen. When the ad is showing (the user opens the app with an active internet connection) i use Padding Widgets as BottomNavigationItems to place my data below the banner ad. If the user opens the app with no active internet connection (either wifi or mobile data) I get the `Ad failed to load : 0` instead of `Ad failed to load : 2` which is the official error code for network errors according to https://support.google.com/admob/thread/3494603?hl=en.

Now ive tried to handle if the ad is loaded or not programatically:

```
void _showBannerAd() async {
    _bannerAd = BannerAd(
        adUnitId: AdManager.bannerAdUnitId,
        size: AdSize.banner,
        targetingInfo: _mobileAdTargetingInfo);

    bool loaded = await _bannerAd.load();
    if (loaded) {
      print('success load');
    } else {
      print('fail load');
    }

    bool showing =
        await _bannerAd.show(anchorOffset: 80.0, anchorType: AnchorType.top);
    if (showing) {
      print('sucess show');
    } else {
      print('fail show');
    }
  }
```

which i load

```
@override
  void initState() {
    _showBannerAd();
    super.initState();
  }
```

But even when there is no internet connection the bool values are false although they shouldnt?
Any help please! I want the user to have a good experience - even with 1 Ad in my entire app it looks weird if the ad is not showing and all the data is still padded.
Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Ive finally found an answer to my own question after searching for a while.
Turns out every Admob ad has a `listener` attribute!
So what i did is
I created a static bool variable in my BottomNavPageState (BottomNavPage is a Statefulwidget) assuming that the user somehow has an internet connection at startup:

```
static bool adError = false;
```

Also every BottomNavItemPage is a StatefulWidget. When initialising my routes i just pass the `adError` variable (at startup) into all the routes which use Ads for now:

```
List<Widget> _routes = [
    TodayPage(),
    PlanPage(adError: adError),
    TodoPage(adError: adError),
    ProgressPage()
  ];
```

When intialising my Banner ad i add the Listener to the banner:

```
void _showBannerAd() async {
    _bannerAd = BannerAd(
        adUnitId: AdManager.bannerAdUnitId,
        size: AdSize.banner,
        targetingInfo: _mobileAdTargetingInfo,
        listener: (event) {
          if (event == MobileAdEvent.failedToLoad) {
            setState(() {
              adError = true;
              _routes = [
                TodayPage(),
                PlanPage(adError: adError),
                TodoPage(adError: adError),
                ProgressPage()
              ];
            });
          }
        });
  }
```

If the ad failes to load i set the State of my BottomNavPageState in which i turn the bool variable to `true` and reinitialise my routes with the new updated bool.
Also dont forget to add the `adError` variable to the BottomNavItemPage:

```
class TodoPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final bool adError;

  TodoPage({this.adError});

  @override
  _TodoPageState createState() => _TodoPageState();
}
...
```

and access the variable to make simple if else check to return the given Padding:

```
...
 Padding(
          padding: widget.adError
              ? EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0, right: 8.0)
              : EdgeInsets.only(top: 60.0, left: 8.0, right: 8.0),
          child: 
...
```

And i have to say it works like a charm!